# select only visible options from multiselect

Tags: jquery

I am Trying to get only visible elements from multiselect.

**Jquery:**

```
var button = $("button")
button.on("click", function(){
  var selectedOpts = $('#test option').prop( "disabled", false );
  console.log(selectedOpts);
})
```

**$('#test option')** returns all the elements

**expected output:** it should return only visible element

**HTML:**

```
<button>select</button>
<select multiple="multiple" id="test" class="form-control">
    <option value="15" style="display: none;">one</option>
    <option value="32" style="display: none;">two</option>
    <option value="68" style="display: none;">three</option>
    <option value="1" style="">four</option>                                                                                          
</select>
```

**Demo code :** https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/109483/

Comment: What does the `.prop( "disabled", false )` have to do with your question? Disabled != invisible

Comment: Use `:visible` to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:visible` attribute selector alongside your `option` selector to get only visible options:

```js
var selectedOpts = $('#test option:visible')
console.log(selectedOpts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>select</button>
<select multiple="multiple" id="test" class="form-control">
    <option value="15" style="display: none;">one</option>
    <option value="32" style="display: none;">two</option>
    <option value="68" style="display: none;">three</option>
    <option value="1" style="">four</option>                                                                                          
</select>
```

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/109563/)

Comment: Did you checked the snippet above? Isn't that what you expect? @JunedAnsari

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this:

```
var button = $("button")
button.on("click", function(){
  var selectedOpts = $('#test option:visible');
  console.log(selectedOpts);
})
```

"disabled" is a completely different thing.

Use these two options in your code to physically see the differece:

```
  <option value="15" disabled>I'm disabled</option> 
  <option value="16" style="display: none;">I'm not visible</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show each visible content.

```js
var selectedOpts = $('#test option:visible');
 selectedOpts.each(function(){    
    console.log($(this).html());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>select</button>
<select multiple="multiple" id="test" class="form-control">
    <option value="15" style="display: none;">one</option>
    <option value="32" style="display: none;">two</option>
    <option value="68" >three</option>
    <option value="1" style="">four</option>                                                                                          
</select>
```